# Formula to determine polygon points of a bounding box created from this equation

Tags: point, extents, linestring

I have a series of points making a linestring
I am trying to detect when a user is within a few meters of any section on the linestring with a tolerance factor
For this, I use this java code (unsure of terminology for this equation, will update question when I know )
The code tests if point (x3,y3) falls (roughly) within the line between the two points

```
    public Boolean isBetween(Location a1, Location b2, Location c3, Double tolerance) {
    Double x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3; 
    //tolerance = 000000010; <= provides about 20m tolerance
    x1 = a1.getLongitude(); // bounding point
    y1 = (a1.getLatitude());
    x2 = b2.getLongitude();//bounding point
    y2 = b2.getLatitude();

    x3 = c3.getLongitude(); //test this point
    y3 = (c3.getLatitude());


    Double px = x2 - x1;
    double py = y2 - y1;
    float norm = (float) (px * px + py * py);
    Double u = ((x3 - x1) * px + (y3 - y1) * py) / norm;

    if (u > 1) {
        u = (double) 1;
    } else if (u < 0) {
        u = (double) 0;
    }


    Double x = x1 + u * px;
    Double y = y1 + u * py;

    Double dx = x - x3;
    Double dy = y - y3;

    Double dist = Math.pow(((dx * dx + dy * dy) * (dx * dx + dy * dy)), .5);
    //Log.d("dbug", "distance= " + dist);
    if (dist < tol) {
        //Log.d("dbug", "is within points= True");
        return true;
    }
    // Log.d("dbug", "is not within points");
    return false;

} //end isbetween
```

This returns a true/false if the point is within a tolerance of the line (usually 10~20m)
What I need is the effective bounding box coordinates, 
Of course creating a bounding box by adding and substracting decimals to the latitude and longitude is ineffective, because the shape changes dramatically as the bearing of the points moves away from north/south to east west and the tolerance is very broad in the middle of the two points

The database that I'm forced to use elsewhere only has isPointWithingPolygon so I need to be able to provide such rectangle.
What formula should I use to determine such points?

Comment: do you really mean bounding box or perhaps you mean buffer? Either way this is a horrible way of doing it. See https://gist.github.com/ianturton/9a7cfee378e7072ec3cd for a better way

Comment: @IanTurton  thought bounding box so I can use a function that determine if a point is inside a polygon , was unaware of terminology, thank you, I will run that code